# Increment variable with number in variable + PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date, variables

I have some variables like this:

```
$_8 = 0; $_9 = 0; $_10 = 0; $_11 = 0; $_12 = 0; $_13 = 0; $_14 = 0; $_15 = 0; $_16 = 0; $_17 = 0; $_18 = 0; $data = array();
```

Then I do the following:

```
$vistoday = $app['db']->fetchAll('SELECT `Datum Bezoek 1` FROM `psttodo-uit` WHERE CAST(`Datum Bezoek 1` AS DATE) = CURRENT_DATE AND PB = 1');

foreach($vistoday as $v){
    $date = strtotime($v['Datum Bezoek 1']);
    $hours = (int)date('h', $date);
    $minutes = (int)date('i', $date);

    if($minutes > 30)
    {
        $hours = $hours + 1;
        $count = ${"_" . $hours} + 1;
        $data[$hours] = $count;
    }
    else
    {
        $data[$hours] = ${"_" . $hours}+1;
    }
}
```

These are the dates I pull from the database:

- 2014-02-27 08:25:34
- 2014-02-27 08:50:34
- 2014-02-27 08:55:34

When I output $data I get this:

```
array (size=2)
   8 => int 1
   9 => int 1
```

But Normally the value of key 9 should be 2. So he doesn't increment, he just adds 1 to nothing. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: You want an array. Repeat after me: This is much better done using an array!

Comment: And how would you do this with an array? Could you give me a tip?

Comment: Also, why dont you count in the database?

Comment: I would have to create 8 queries or so like BETWEEN ... AND ... ? That's more performant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yoг don't need variables like $_8

```
foreach($vistoday as $v){
    $date = strtotime($v['Datum Bezoek 1']);
    $hours = (int)date('h', $date);
    $minutes = (int)date('i', $date);

    $hours = round($hours + $minutes / 61); // if $minutes > 30 ceil else floor
    $data[$hours] = isset($data[$hours]) ? $data[$hours] + 1 : 1;
}
```